# Pass a value in document.write

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have a `<script>` that creates a tagId value.

Currently, it will display as `document.write(tagId);`

I want to place tagId in a `<form>` as:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="tagId">
```

Example, something like:

```js
document.write(< input type="text" name="" value="tagId" >);
```

How can I place the `tagID` value to insert in the text form?

Comment: [Avoid `document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use JS string templates ('template literals'), ie strings in which JS expressions (eg. plain variables, as in your case) are interpolated:

```
document.write(`<input type="text" name="" value="${tagId}">`);
```

You have to use backticks (``` `` ```) as string delimiters. The expression(s) are referenced per `${<expression_goes_here>}`. The expression is serialized as it would elsewhere in the code.

See [here (MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more info.

Comment: Hi, your answer is great, but it is not passing the tagID value?

Comment: @MarkM It does. The template is interpolated (ie. the evaluation results of referenced expressions, in your case the contents of `tagId`) automatically by the JS engine. Drop `let tagId = 'blarf'; console.log(\`<input type="text" name="" value="${tagId}">\`);` into your browser console to see it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The console.log:
<input type="text" name="" value="2501006464102020100101102051080192024">

But if I look at the source code:
document.write(`<input type="text" name="" value="${tagId}">`);

Comment: should the form have the same value entered?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: Sure, Since the goal is to get the tagID into the form text while the console.log:

<input type="text" name="" value="2501006464102020100101102051080192024">

document.write(`<input type="text" name="" value="${tagId}">`);

But, in source code, I do no see the output. Would this require a "print"
of something so that I can use the form text as a value?

so that this is in the page:

<input type="text" name="" value="2501006464102020100101102051080192024">

Comment: What do you mean with 'source code'? Which tools do you use to inspect it? Why would you expect to see the instantiated values in the source code representation? Client-side you can inspect the DOM (~ html structure) parts built from the `document.write` calls (right mouse click over one of the input elements). Do you want to programmatically generate the script that would write parts of the document when executed in the browser? In the latter case you would have to define the whole `document.write` call as (part of) a string.

Comment: I'm not sure. I open the webpage source code hoping to view the < text > -- within my form /form

Comment: In the latter case you would have to define the whole document.write call as (part of) a string -- can you give me an example?

Comment: What would you need that feature for?

Comment: I have a form post and I want to pass the tagID as a hidden text /form

Comment: You do not need a source code representation for that. I think I still do not properly understand you though. The input fields generated have the `tagID`s as their values. These values will be part of the POST request when submitting the form (as long as you issue proper `name` attributes to the `input` elements. If you want the data to be hidden (ie. no fields for user interaction), use `type='hidden'`. Example: `document.write(<input type="hidden" name="parameter-${i}" value="${tagId}">);`, if i was the variable you iterate over in your script.

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry I am a newbie with javascript. i will try it in the form. Is there a way to assign this value so that appears in a <textarea> with other attributes?

Comment: No problem. Try `document.write(\`<textarea rows="2" cols="80" name="parameter-${i}">${tagId}</textarea>\`);`.

Comment: Well, I added the script to a form post. the name="uid"  that I want to pass to the next page. It does not appear from the post.

Comment: do I write it differently: document.write(<input type="hidden" name="uid-${i}" value="${tagId}">);

Comment: No thats ok. You have to check the server-side processing. Do you perhaps assume server-side that the name of the form fields is `uid`? (Technically you could do that. The parameter value would then effectively be a list of values. However, this might need special processing depending on your server-side development platform).

Comment: The issuse would not be the server side. All the hidden attributes a process. I can see the uid is not being posted. I really appreciate your efforts. Perhaps if you make a simple html form post and look for the value in the page you will see what I am describing. The post is how to get the uid to post in a form.

Comment: The way you use it, the `uid` is the parameter name. If you want to post it as a value, you need to define a form parameter and create an input field for holding the value. At this stage I think we will not progress without you providing more info about code and environment  (in the form of a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): The html sent to the client, the server processing code, if applicable the server-side html generating code.

Comment: I think it fairly simple:
  form action="https://somewebpage.com/" method="POST" 
   <input type = "hidden" name = "name1" value = "Some name 1">
   <input type = "hidden" name = "name2" value = "Some name 2">
   <input type = "hidden" name = "uid" value = "${uId}">
/form

Comment: name1 and name2 process

Comment: perhaps the , script > should be outside of the < form > , /form> with the write. inside?

Comment: I just double checked with a web proxy, the technique works perfectly (using current version of Chrome), the dynamically created parts of the form are sent along with their statically defined counterparts. The issue must be with you specific client environment or (very likely !) server-side. Impossible to tell more without you providing actual code.

Comment: If you wish to analyze the request sent from your form yourself, try [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as a handy tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a specific reason for using `document.write`, the better approach would be to create an element and append it to a div in your document

```js
const container = document.getElementById("addForm")
// Create element:
var input = document.createElement("input");
var tagId = "your tag ID"
input.type = "text";
input.name = ""
input.value = tagId

// Append to body:
container.appendChild(input);
```

```html
<div id="addForm"></div>
```

Comment: ok, does <div id="addForm"></div>   get added within the < form > tags >? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you can add it wherever you want in the document

Comment: @MarkM that should be pretty straightforward

Comment: I have it working, thank you very much! Will keep your connection, One last question? I assigned all of the < hidden text > tags. In my sample, I have 3 different html < select > options, I can't seem to get them to appear on the page coded within the < script >

Comment: function post_to_url(url, obj) {
      let id=`form_${+new Date()}`;
      document.body.innerHTML+=`
        <form id="${id}" action="${url}" method="POST">
          ${Object.keys(obj).map(k=>`

Comment: is there a attribute that will let me use an html < select >  within the < script > ?

Comment: Your code `let id=form_${+new Date()}` is wrong, it should be  `let id = \`form_${+new Date()}\` `

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>

function post_to_url(url, obj) {
  let id = `form_${+new Date()}`
  document.body.innerHTML+=`
    <form id="${id}" action="${url}" method="POST">
      ${Object.keys(obj).map(k=>`
     <input type = "hidden" name = "goTagID" value = "${tagID}">

// would like these html options to show
      <select name="Option1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
      <select name="Option2">
      <option value="Cosmic Sky">Cosmic Sky</option>
      <option value="Magical Petroglyphs">Magical Petroglyphs</option>
      <option value="Spiral Dancers">Spiral Dancers</option>
      <option value="Minoan Octopus">Minoan Octopus</option>
      </select>
      `)}

    </form>`
  this[id].submit();
}

// TEST - in second param object can have more keys
function post() { post_to_url('https://somedomain/', {'q':'a'}); }
</script>

The HTML does not appear in the page
```